# Indusoft Web Studio Error Messages?

Tags: scada, industrial, wonderware

Apologies if this is a pretty simple question, but I'm pretty new to IWS.

When ever I startup IWS (it's running on Microsoft Server that I remote desktop into) and enter my login details I get this message:

> Failed to start TCP/IP Server, please check if the TCP port is already in use

During this same session I will also get the message below whenever I try to change tags in my trend sheets:

> WARNING: Tag changes in any trend group will only take place in the next day history file.

It seems any changes I make in relation to tags and driver sheets are ignored and I want to know if this is related to the above error messages and how do I go about debugging/fixing this?

Note: I do not get these messages in other IWS sessions on other servers and I don't experience these problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projects running the TCP/IP Server task use a TCP Port that is defined in the [InduSoft Project Settings - Communication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI1Cc.jpg) tab.  By default, InduSoft uses port 1234.  The error message you mention can occur if another process binds to that port before InduSoft has started the TCP/IP Server task.

Answer (score 0):

Change the TCP Port. 1234 is the standard Port for Indusoft.

Try to Map your useds Ports before chosing some.

Or kill the process that are using the Port 1234, as explained in the link.

https://receitasdecodigo.com.br/java/listar-e-matar-processo-pela-porta-em-uso-no-windows-pelo-cmd